# Which race in the Star Trek universe has the most advanced technology?

Tags: star-trek

I'm not talking about the Q, since I don't think that it can really be considered 'technology' as such. I'm certain it isn't the Federation, and in Voyager's Eye of the Needle the Romulans say that the Federation are advanced in ways which the Romulans are not, yet he was 20 years out of time.

I'm not bothered about the most 'powerful race' after reading a question which seems to be, on the surface, the same question as this - I mean purely technological advancements, hopefully someone can provide a few examples of races which are more advanced than the Federation and the specific areas of advancement.

Comment: This is highly subjective.  "Most advanced technology" is a fairly vague and subjective term.  For example, some would say what the Q do is advanced technology based.  Also, some races are more advanced in some areas and others are more advanced in other areas.

Comment: do you want to know litterally everyone, or major players, some of the more advanced species are seen very briefly here or their so theirs not much known about them.

Comment: i think we usually think of the Q's as more of an ascended being. living at a higher level of existence. at least that was my understanding.

Comment: As a single game of Civilization has taught me, you can learn the secrets of Nuclear Fusion without ever having developed electricity.  Technological advances are tree-shaped, not line-shaped.

Comment: *hopefully someone can provide a list of races which are more advanced than the Federation and the specific areas of advancement.* That would be a "list question" which are out of scope for the site.

Comment: Edited. I don't want an exhaustive list, just a few examples of technology more advanced than what the Federation are in possession of.

Comment: its no longer a list question, and its not really opinions, there are many races clearly technologically superior to the federation.

Comment: @Zibbobz, then you come to silly things like learning "Advanced Flight" without learning "Flight" first...

Comment: @Himarm The Romulan quoted in the question makes my point for me:  No two species advanced the same, and technological advancement is not a linear path.  No species can be considered "more" advanced than others because of this, making the _criteria_ for "most advanced" fit "primarily opinion-based".  But I'd probably have gone with "Too Broad", since people can keep popping in with a Voyager enemy-of-the-week saying, "but they don't have _this_ technology!"

Comment: @Zibbobz: In *Civilization IV*, you can bee-line physics to get airships. This is a good way of using air power if you're isolated and lacking resources such as iron and coal. This question is about *Civilization*, right?

Answer (score 8):

While every race can have areas in which they are the most advanced, and other areas where theyare years behind, some of the biggest players in the star trek universe that seem to have tech 100s of years beyond the federation, (which is pretty much the most advanced "humanoids" in at least the alpha and beta quadrants.(their could be a few exceptions))

V'Ger - extremely advanced technological life form. created from our own voyager probe was given life by an unknown race of sentient machines. lives in a massive ship and can do things the federation has never seen, nor can replicate.

The above Sentient machine race, nothing is known about them except that they created V'Ger.

The Iconians- extremely advanced race believed to be extinct 200,000 years ago. They essentially made star-gates across the galaxy creating instantaneous travel between planets across the galaxy. currently slated to be the next villainous race after the borg.

The race that build the Whale Probe, again a massive ship that is able to make all federation tech null. again nothing is known about them except that they are far older and more advanced then the humanoids of earth at least.

The preservers, or progenitors the race that seeded humanoid life in the alpha and beta quadrants. again little is known of them but the fact that 100s of thousands of years ago they seeded all humanoid life, leads us to believe they are extremely advanced.

Finally we have the Borg, while not making their own tech so much, anyone they meet they can assimilate their tech, increasing their own technology, limitlessly. as of TNG/Voyager far beyond federation tech.

Comment: Don't forget the race that built the Guardian of Time. Or the Iconians - their technology was almost like magic to the crew of the Enterprise.

Comment: i was thinking about the iconians, but i forgot their name >.> is sto their are actually active and will replace the borg as the final villians or at least the next evil power after the borg.

Comment: The [Organians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Organian) were also pretty advanced.

Comment: Vidiian medical science, the Tkon outposts, the Caretaker, the people [from this episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(episode)), the Krenim time manipulation, perhaps even Hirogen weapons - the list goes on and on...

Comment: @izkata all of the races listed above are not more addvanced in just 1 area, they are overwhelmingly hundreds if not thousands of years ahead of the federation and the standard tech in alpha and beta quadrant. yes some races in the quadrent are far more advanced it X while behind in Y, these races are ahead in XYZ.

Comment: @Himarm Which is exactly what the question is asking for in the last sentence

Comment: @izkata i was referencing to your post above, not here my fault.

Comment: The Iconians, evil?  Wow, that's a surprise and a shame, given how Picard expounded on his belief that, while the Iconians were perceived as evil by those they interacted with, they were most likely misunderstood.

Comment: @Michael in STO,they simply have a different set of morals, which compared to our morals makes them evil, but by their own morals they are not, so i guess they are miss understood haha.

Comment: Cytherians are a race so advanced they functionally enact the same mission as Star Fleet, not by exploring the stars, but by **bringing other races to THEIR space** and exchanging information. They were able to do this in *TNG* by "reprogramming" the brain of Reginald Barclay, making him, in Dr Crusher's words "the most advanced human to ever live" with an IQ of 1450. He melded with the Enterprise computer and created a singularity which brought the ship to the center of the Milky Way to meet with the Cytherians; Picard said the data gained would "take Star Fleet scholars decades to decipher."